# Weird bug with SSH, Unison and Samba?

Tags: server, ssh, samba

I am running two servers, one at home (Server 1) and one at the office (Server 2). Both of these servers run a couple of Samba share directories which are synced every 30 minutes with Unison - the synchronization is initiated and ran on server 2.

All was working fine for a couple of weeks until suddenly the servers stopped syncing, upon further inspection it turned out that Server 2 was unable to initiate an SSH connection to my home server, when debugging with -vvv SSH transfer stopped at 'SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY'.

I have setup SSH keys for the office server to connect to the home server and that all works fine. Goggling this issue I found out that this is supposedly an Ubuntu/SSH bug and is easily rectified by either setting the MTU of the network interface to a lower value in the range of 500-1200; or by un-commenting the 'Ciphers' and 'HostKeyAlgorithms' options in the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.

Both of these solve the SSH connection problem, however when I lower the MTU setting of the network interface to 500, this fixes the SSH problem and Unison runs fine, but Samba breaks and the Server no longer shows up in Windows Explorer and I am unable to access any files without restarting the box manually.

On the other hand, when I un-comment the ciphers and host key algorithms options in the SSH file, SSH works and Samba continues to work; however Unison then stalls after connecting at "Setting permissions mask to 0".

I am a bit stuck on what to do as both SSH solutions break a part of my server setup. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Solved. Setting MTU to 1200 and using crontab to run this at reboot seems to have solved the problem.